# How to hit "Esc" key as well when clicking the type="reset" button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to trigger the hitting of "Esc" key as well when clicking the `<input type="reset">` button? ( For some reason, the existing function needs Esc to work properly. )

To be precise, the desired result is:

1. Typing in the input field
2. Click "Reset"
3. Clear input **+** **Hitting the "Esc" key**

Here is the form created for example:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); myFunction();">
  <input type="text" id="quick-search" required="" />
  <input type="reset" id="reset-btn" value="Reset" />
</form>
<style>
  input#quick-search:not(:valid)~input#reset-btn {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.key === "Escape") {
      $("#reset-btn").click();
    }
  });
</script>
```

I know how to make "Esc" as clicking `reset`, but cannot find the answer to make clicking `reset` also comes with a hit on "Esc".

Comment: Why do you need to click `reset-btn`? If `reset-btn`is calling a function, why do not call that function?

Comment: @NairiAbgaryan Thanks, some constraints in the situation make me only able to do this, the quickest way. I know how to make "Esc" as clicking reset, but cannot find the answer to make clicking reset also a hit on "Esc"

Comment: you can check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comment on the question.

The script turns out be like this:

```
var esc = jQuery.Event("keypress");
esc.keyCode = 27;
$("#reset-btn").trigger(esc);
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55102965/1468253

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).on('keyup', function(event) {
         if (event.key == "Escape") {
            $("#reset-btn").click();
         }
    });
```

```css
 input#quick-search:not(:valid)~input#reset-btn {
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); myFunction();">
  <input type="text" id="quick-search" required="" />
  <input type="reset" id="reset-btn" value="Reset" />
</form>
```